# Python post запрос

Tags: python

Отправляю post запрос в обработчик формы с помощью библиотеки [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org). При добавлении файла в запрос, текстовые данные, передаваемые в запросе, на сайте отображаются в другой кодировке. Если не пересылать файл, то такой проблемы нет. В чем может быть причина?

Код:

```
text_data['phone'] = 'phone'
text_data['email'] = 'email'
files_data['userfile'] = open('C:\\picture.jpg', 'rb') 
requests.post('e1.ru/add.php', files=files_data, data=text_data, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Покажите исходный код, пожалуйста.

Comment: вот код:
text_data['phone'] = 'phone'
text_data['email'] = 'email'

files_data['userfile'] = open('C:\\picture.jpg', 'rb')

requests.post('http://www.e1.ru/add.php', files=files_data, data=text_data, cookies=cookies)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в кодировке. Либо файла, либо запроса. Везде необходимо указывать кодировку, чтобы избегать таких неприятностей, как у вас

Comment: Или отправлять в UTF-8. ;-)

Comment: указывать кодировку, в том числе, и при отправке запросов. Да

Comment: а как указать кодирвку в запросе, покажите пожалуйста